# Subversion files mistakenly commited as binary

Tags: svn

We have been having issues where employees commit the SQL files  *.SQL  files accidently or by mistake as binary instead of text. Is there an easy way to change the format in Collabnet Subversion of files ending in *.SQL to text. The problem is that Subversion does not show the revisioncorrectly when it does a DIFF between the text file & binary. If we commit again as text then it is a text to text DIFF. 
Text to Binary DIFF shows this below when there are changes:

```
- No changes -
Diff Legend

–   Removed lines
+   Added lines
<   Changed lines
>   Changed lines
```

Any easy way to convert or prevent the incorrect checkin?
Any way subversion can check if file extension is *.sql and convert/prevent it as being commited as binary?
Any way to identify all files ending *.SQL which are saved as binary instead of text in subversion?
Can this be done within subversion or with Tortoise without any other tools?

Answer (score 3):

Subversion doesn't really have Text vs Binary mode with files. All files are stored in the same format.

In Subversion, all a *binary* file means is that Subversion shouldn't try to merge this file, or do a text diff on it.

Subversion determines whether or not a file is a text file by setting a file property called `svn:mime-type`. If this isn't set, the file is a text file. If it is set, the file is assumed to be binary. (It might still be considered a text file if the mime-type starts with `text/`, but I'm not 100% sure...)

What you need to do is to configure your mime-type file to understand that `*.sql` files are text files. If you use Apache httpd for your Subversion server, you can edit the `mime-types` file that usually sits in the `conf` directory where `httpd.conf` is located.

You can also set this on a per-user basis by setting your `$HOME/.subversion/config` file in Unix, or by editing your Subversion Registry Entries on Windows.

What you do is setup a *mime types* file, and then point the `mime-types-file` entry to that file.

The [MIME types file](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml) is simply a two column affair with the *MIME type* in the first column and the suffix in the second column. You need to add something like this:

```
text/sql              sql
```

This will guarantee that any file that ends in `*.sql` is a text file.

For the files you've entered, just remove the property on them:

```
$ svn propdel svn:mime-type *.sql
$ svn commit -m"Making my SQL files text files"
```